# node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'Routes'

Tags: angular

I am trying to make routing in my angular2 application. I just tried to follow [this link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

But in the `app.routing.ts` in line:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from   '@angular/router';
```

**It complains with:**

```
node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'Routes'.
```

and

```
node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterModule'.
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
```

As you see, i am using `"@angular/router": "^3.0.0-alpha.7",`, but it does not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Routes is only an import for the new version of the router. If you wish to use it, you must update your project to the new RC.5 version of the router.

edit:
also is you navigate to your node_modules then @angular/router/index.d.ts then you will be able to see the available imports for your router version.

Comment: Also to piggyback on to this answer if the OP does not want to upgrade to RC.5 for now they should change `Routes` to `RouterConfig` and get rid of the `RoutesModule`

Answer (score 1):

you are using older version of router . the newer version is `"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-rc.1"` as seen in [change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/CHANGELOG.md#300-rc1-2016-08-09)

update your app to angular `rc5` as well.